# How to read Pipe("|") deliminated file in spring batch processing

Tags: spring-batch, delimiter

I am trying to read `.dat` file which contains text which is delimited by the pipe symbol: `|`

How can I use spring-batch processing to read a file deliminated with this character?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] of the site to understand how stackoverflow works and how to ask good  questions. Then come back and [edit] your question. Include the code of what you've tried as a [mcve], plus any error messages. Ask specific questions. Most people are happy to help, but don't want to do your work for you. Questions like "how do I do x?" that don't show any research effort on your end are likely to get ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Java config for defining custom **Delimiter**

```
 public FlatFileItemReader<POJO> reader() {         

                return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<POJO>().resource(new UrlResource(filename))
                        .name("Reader")
                        .delimited()
                        .delimiter("|")
                        .names("Your File Header")
                        .targetType(POJO.class)                 
                        .build();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example in the getting started guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

To set a custom delimiter, use the `delimiter` method: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/builder/FlatFileItemReaderBuilder.DelimitedBuilder.html#delimiter-java.lang.String-